# Chromium source code compiling

Tags: c++, chromium

I'm trying to compile the chromium source code Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.09. I'm getting the following error.

```
../../chromium/src/third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h:41:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
```

Comment: I can compile the same on Ubuntu.

Comment: You do have a C++ standard library installed in the compilers search paths? Because that's a *C++* standard header file, not C.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very familar with C++ I've installed the following packages su -c 'yum install subversion pkgconfig python perl gcc-c++ bison \
flex gperf nss-devel nspr-devel gtk2-devel glib2-devel freetype-devel \
atk-devel pango-devel cairo-devel fontconfig-devel GConf2-devel \
dbus-devel alsa-lib-devel libX11-devel expat-devel bzip2-devel \
dbus-glib-devel elfutils-libelf-devel libjpeg-devel \
mesa-libGLU-devel libXScrnSaver-devel \
libgnome-keyring-devel cups-devel libXtst-devel libXt-devel pam-devel'

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, worked perfectly on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chromium requirements section says:

> You should be able to build Chromium on any reasonably modern Linux
>   distribution, but there are a lot of distributions and we sometimes
>   break things on one or another. Internally, our development platform
>   has been a variant of Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr); we expect you will
>   have the most luck on this platform, although directions for other
>   popular platforms are included below.

I was not able to compile Chromium on OpenSuSE without lots of troubles, but as in your case, it worked fine on Ubuntu for me.